# xargs adds whitespace after echo statement when outputting on to new line

Tags: bash, echo, xargs

using xargs and echo to output result of samtools to new line in output.txt file

```
samtools view $SAMPLE\.bam | cut -f3 | uniq -c | sort -n | \
xargs -r0 -n1 echo -e "Summarise mapping...\n" >> ../output.txt
```

This adds the result on a new line after the echo but also adds a space before the result on the first new line, how can i stop this?

Comment: If you add a sample of the output of the first command, your expected output and the actual output, people can help you without having to have samtools installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `xargs` which is adding the space. It's the `echo` command:

> The echo utility arguments shall be *separated by single `<space>` characters* and a `<newline>` character shall follow the last argument. (Text from [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); emphasis added.)

If you want more control, use [`printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html):

```
...
xargs -r0 -n1 printf "Summarise mapping...\n%s\n" >> ../output.txt
```

Unlike `printf` does not automatically add a newline at the end, so it needs to be included in the format.

Note that `printf` automatically interprets escape sequence like `\n` in the format string (but not in interpolated arguments). As an additional bonus for using `printf`, you could leave out the `-n1` option since `printf` automatically repeats the format until all arguments are consumed.